# Clicking a button to switch the language

Tags: android, localization, resources

When I click on the "sub_changelang" button, it should change the program language to French for example. I got the following code to change the locale but I have no idea how to refresh/ pdate the app to change the language to French.

```
Button cl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub_changelang); 
cl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{ 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v)
    { 
        Locale locale = new Locale("fr_FR"); 
        Locale.setDefault(locale); 
        Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
        config.locale = locale; 
    } 
});
```

It doesn't work. How can I fix it?  I tried to add:

```
MainActivity.this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, MainActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

but it didn't work.  I also tried:

```
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                          getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

and it didn't work either.

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

is set inside the AndroidMainfest.xml under application -> activity

Comment: you need to relaunch your Activity after changing the locale

Comment: It did change the buttons text but not the whole app UI

Comment: I am using same code as u...and my app is working fine

Comment: Just check the next screen UI..

Comment: I mean, it didnt change the app name (in the ui itself ofc)

Comment: make sure you have app_name in French in you Strings.xml file

Comment: I do have app_name in my strings.xml. it just not applying it when refreshing the app, can u show me your full onClick function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28104/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-srivastava-and-ron)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am using this code to set locale

```
String languageToLoad  = "fr_FR";
     Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
     Locale.setDefault(locale);
     Configuration config = new Configuration();
     config.locale = locale;
     context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

Intent intent = new Intent(XYZ.this, XYZ.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

here context is application Base Context. 
**Please also try "fr" instead of "fr_FR"** because I am working for Arabic locale and its working fine.

You need to restart your Activity after changing locale.

Comment: do you know how to be in fragments with navigation drawer?its work but i have only mainactivity others are fragments so how can i change it in fragment,know if i will change it in another fragment it will intent to mainactivity?

Comment: This thread is not related to fragment. You can ask new question about this or search same thread. By the way, you can set listener to know the fragment change event and then update navigation drawer according to your fragment requirement. See this document reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html

Comment: How to change text without restart activity.

Answer (score 7):

You can use activity.this.recreate().But it will support from API level 11.