# How to change language of app when click button in Android

Tags: android

When I click a button, I want to change language in my Android app.

`Eg: Current language in app is English and then i click a button, language will change to Vietnamese.`

This is the first time I do it. But I do not know how I do?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same question in below link. This might help you. Change the language to Vietnamese instead of france
[Clicking a button to switch the language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970271/button-click-change-language-to-france)